# How to create Advanced Search filter Angular firestore using Typescript?

Tags: search, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, advanced-custom-fields

How to create Advanced Search  filter Angularfirestore using Typescript ?

```
search = this.afs.collection('City');
search.ref.where('areaList', '==', this.data.area[_i])
.where('price', '>=', this.data.minPrice)
.where('price', '<=', this.data.maxPrice)
```

If I use only one input give me error need to fill other inputs, I wanna separate between operations  and use as needed .

All data was saved in firestore.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I need advanced search